# create a List of object based on a function's parameter

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How to create a List of object based on a function's parameter ? Following is my code :

```
List<ItemMaster> list = new List<ItemMaster>();

foreach (DataRow row in resp.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ItemMaster item = new ItemMaster();
    foreach (PropertyInfo vr in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (resp.DataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(vr.Name.ToString()))
        {
            vr.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(row[vr.Name], vr.PropertyType), null);
        }
    }

    list.Add(item);
}
```

I have multiple classes like ItemMaster, so was thinking to make a function which takes DataTable and Class as parameter and which will return the list of that particular class which is passed in the function's parameter.

How can this be implemented

Comment: The code you posted seems to implement what you are asking about. So, what _specifically_ are you having problems with? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how to include a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that illustrates your question, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to write a clear, useful question.

Comment: the code I have posted is for a particular Class. I have multiple classes like that, and I need to convert DataTable to List of that particular class. In above condition I have to write the code n times for n classes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I think I understand your question better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems that you are having trouble coming up with a single method implementation that would work for any arbitrary item type. If that's correct, then something like this might work in your case:

```
List<T> FillListFromTable<T>(DataTable dataTable) where T : new()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        T item = new T();

        foreach (PropertyInfo vr in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(vr.Name))
            {
                vr.SetValue(item,
                    Convert.ChangeType(row[vr.Name], vr.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
List<ItemMaster> itemMasterList = FillListFromTable<ItemMaster>(resp.DataSet.Tables[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a generic. As a bonus you can return a generic list.

```
List<T> ToList<T>(DataSet dataset): new()
{

    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow row in resp.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (PropertyInfo vr in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (resp.DataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(vr.Name.ToString()))
            {
                vr.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(row[vr.Name], vr.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }

        list.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Generic method, and All class can implement specific interface.

```
public IList<T> CreateList<T>(Datatable table) where T : IInterface
```

Comment: It's funny they voted me minus then post same answer :D

Comment: Does not even compile? Whats a "Datetable"? And you'll need the `new()` generic thingy to create instances. The interface will not help much here.

Comment: I guess everyone knows Datetable is mistyping of Datatable,also is just template not final code. If you read my description then you find I said you can use specefic interface to specify the classes